# problem creating and editing features at extent edges

Tags: arcgis-10.0, features, editing, wgs84

I'm in the process of creating a polyline feature layer of tectonic plates. I'm working with WGS-84 reference system, which means the extent is +-180 in lon, and +-90 in lat. 
In order to create the features in a correct way, I imported a CSV file with the 4 "corners" and displayed them as points I then snap my features to when I create them.

The problems arises when I want to snap the line to the edge point. It simply doesn't want to create the line all the way, cutting it shy of the actual point.

Here's what I see:
[image]

The coordinate is that of my cursor. The green point is (-180,-90).

The green background is another layer I used (continents) to see if there's some kind of error or a general problem, but as you can see, it sits perfectly in place.

I have tried different editor tools (line, polygon, autocomplete), but the problem persists.

I have also tried to extend that segment the the point, as well as moving a node to the point, but it doesn't edit it, and jumps back to it's previous position.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Maybe [useful](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22188/why-wont-arcmap-10-snap). Also what happens if you try placing a point at -180,-90 using [absolute X,Y?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/at_an_exact_x_y_location_absolute_x_y/01m70000006m000000/)

Comment: @MatthewSnape It doesn't execute, and the abs. xy window closes.
As for the other link, all other editing and snap functionality works just fine when it's not at the edges.

Comment: If its just four points you could try running the [envelope tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000)

Comment: @MatthewSnape I will try it first thing in the morning, thanks.

Comment: Well, the envelope worked, but the error was something else which I overlooked. The layer itself I was trying to edit wasn't, in fact, in wgs 84. Snapping the lines to the full extent wasn't possible because of that.